# how to create android linearlayout cornar crap color?

Tags: android, layout, colors, android-linearlayout

I am new android devloper..

I want to do android linearlayout cornar crap color. I tried. I did not get the corner grab I saw. Below is my silk to give my linearlayout.

LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:background="@color/gnt_ad_green"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:weightSum="4.0">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="Intergiration"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_filter"
        android:drawablePadding="10.0dip"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:padding="15.0dip"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="16.0sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/colorBackgroundLight"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3.0">
        <TextView android:textSize="12.0sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="sdfsdf gd"

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want a design like this
[simple image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4ZXL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

rect_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#F00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="110"
            android:pivotX="90%"
            android:pivotY="90%"
            >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="#FFF" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rect_background"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to use the image for this (add an image which contains a shape like this) and set this image as a background of your linear layout.